# Neo4j-graphql self reference type is empty

Tags: neo4j, graphql, apollo-server, neo4j-graphql-js

Trying neo4j with graphql using apollo and neo4j-graphql-js. Here is my typeDefs:

```
const typeDefs = `
        type Employee {
            eid: ID!
            name: String!
            title: String!
            email: String
            reportees: [Employee] @relation(name: "REPORTS_TO", direction: "IN")
        }

        type Query {
            getAllEmployees: [Employee] @cypher(statement: "MATCH (n) RETURN n")
            getEmployee(name: String): [Employee] @cypher(statement: "MATCH (e:EMP) WHERE e.name contains $name RETURN e")
        }
`;
```

I always get reportees as empty. Any suggestions on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved - I had type as Employee and node as EMP. Changing type to EMP did the trick.